# Left outer join with null LINQ exception with Guids

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, guid

I am trying to do a left outer join with null in linq over a List, so if I have one list with {1,2,3,4} and other with {1,2,3,5}, I want the {4}.

[image]

```
IEnumerable<AlertChangeSet> listToClear = from a in AlertsCached
                                                  join b in loadedAlerts on a.AlertId equals b.AlertId into c
                                                  from b in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                  select new AlertChangeSet()
                                                       {
                                                           AlertId = b.AlertId == Guid.Empty ? a.AlertId : Guid.Empty

                                                       };
  if (listToClear.Any())
        {
            foreach (AlertChangeSet alertChangeSet in listToClear)
            {
                Guid a = alertChangeSet.AlertId;
                //SystemMonitoringService.ClearAlertAsync(alertChangeSet.AlertId.ToString(), null);
            }
        }
```

When I run this code,  I get this exception:

> Test method
>   Tgw.Systems.Alerting.Server.Test.ConfigurationTests.UpdateCacheWith2recordsSameIdWorking
>   threw exception:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object. at
>   Tgw.Wcs.Alerting.MonitoringAddIn.Oms.Wcf.OmsWcfSystemMonitor.b__c(<>f__AnonymousType0`2
>   <>h__TransparentIdentifier2, AlertChangeSet b) in
>   OmsWcfSystemMonitor.cs: line 255 at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__31`3.MoveNext() at
>   Tgw.Wcs.Alerting.MonitoringAddIn.Oms.Wcf.OmsWcfSystemMonitor.UpdateAlertsFromCache(IList`1
>   loadedAlerts) in OmsWcfSystemMonitor.cs: line 275 at
>   Tgw.Systems.Alerting.Server.Test.ConfigurationTests.UpdateCacheWith2recordsSameIdWorking()
>   in ConfigurationTests.ServerCoreTests.cs: line 243

I think the problem is the Guid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
AlertId = b.AlertId ?? a.AlertId ?? Guid.Empty;
```

because b can be `null` you cannot compare it to Guid.Empty

`??` is the null-coalescing operator. That means that the statement will use the first not-null value for the assignment.

// **EDIT**:

You are right. I didn't test it.

```
AlertId = ( b == null ) ? a.AlertId : Guid.Empty;
```

This here should work. Guid was a special case, because it cannot be null by design.

Comment: The Guid is not nullable and cannot be converted to Guid? so I get a compilation error: "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid'"